# How does $a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{n^2}{a_n}$ grow?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a positive sequence such that $a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{n^2}{a_n}$. What is the rate of growth of $a_n$?

I have seen [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2679220/cesaro-stolz-limit?noredirect=1) which deals with $a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{n^{1/2}}{a_n}$, but I am not sure how to apply that theorem of Cesaro-Stolz here.

Comment: You can look at this as the discrete analog of the differential equation $\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{x^2}{f(x)}$, take an ansatz of $f(x)\propto x^\beta$ for some $\beta$, and then solve a simple linear equation to find out what $\beta$ has to be. This is heuristic but should still give the right answer.

Comment: Thanks, using this I get $\beta = \frac{3}{2}$. I assume I can apply Cesaro-Stolz now, but I'm having a bit of trouble here too: how do I deal with $(n+1)^{3/2}-n^{3/2}$ in the denominator? And I'm not sure how to prove the limit exists, either.

Comment: @yokov_dubachev $$
(n + 1)^{3/2}  - n^{3/2}  = \frac{{(n + 1)^3  - n^3 }}{{(n + 1)^{3/2}  + n^{3/2} }}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing,
consider

$a_{n+1} 
= a_n + \dfrac{n^c}{a_n}
$
where
$c > 0$
and
$a_1 = a > 0$.

I can show that
$a(c+1)\ln(m)+O(1)
\lt a_m
\lt \dfrac{m^{c+1}}{a(c+1)}+O(m^c)
$.

I am pretty sure that
the upper bound
is the correct order of magnitude,
but I can't prove it now.

We have
$a_{n+1} > a_n$
so
$a_{n+1} 
\gt a_n + \dfrac{n^c}{a_{n+1}}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
a_m-a_1
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} (a_{n+1}-a_n)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}  \dfrac{n^c}{a_n}\\
&\lt\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}  \dfrac{n^c}{a}\\
&=\dfrac1{a}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}n^c\\
&=\dfrac1{a}(\dfrac{m^{c+1}}{c+1}+O(m^c))\\
\end{array}
$

so

$a_m
\lt a+\dfrac1{a}(\dfrac{m^{c+1}}{c+1}+O(m^c))
= \dfrac{m^{c+1}}{a(c+1)}+O(m^c)
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
a_m-a_1
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}  \dfrac{n^c}{a_n}\\
&\gt\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}  \dfrac{n^c}{\dfrac{n^{c+1}}{a(c+1)}+O(n^c)}\\
&\gt\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}  \dfrac{n^{-1}}{\dfrac{1}{a(c+1)}+O(n^{-1})}\\
&=a(c+1)(\ln(m)+O(1))\\
\end{array}
$

so

$a_m
\gt a(c+1)\ln(m)+O(1)
$.

Comment: If the order of magnitude were $n^{c+1}$ wouldn't this imply that $a_{n+1}-a_n = \frac{n^c}{a_n}\to 0$ for $n\to \infty$, giving a contradiction?

Comment: Also: is the following reasoning correct? 
A tighter lower bound is obtained by considering that 
$$f_n(x) = x+\frac{n^c}{x}$$ 
has a minimum in $\overline x = n^{\frac{c}2}$, with $f_n(\overline x) = 2n^{\frac{c}2}$. Therefore 
$$a_n = a_{n-1}+\frac{(n-1)^c}{a_{n-1}}\geq 2 (n-1)^{\frac{c}2}$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is now completely reviewed thanks to [Gary](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83800/gary)'s useful comments.

1. First note that
   $$a_{n+1} = f_n(a_n)$$ where
   $$f_n(x) = x + \frac{n^2}x\geq 2n,$$
   for $x>0$, so that $$a_{n}\geq 2(n-1)\geq n,\tag{1}\label{1}$$
   for $n\geq 2$, and the sequence is divergent.
2. Now observe that $$a_{n+1}^2 = a_n^2\left(1+\frac{n^2}{a_n^2}\right)^2,$$ so that letting $b_n = a_n^2$ yields
   $$b_{n+1} = g_n(b_n),$$
   where
   $$g_n(x) = x\left(1+\frac{n^2}x\right)^2.$$
   The above function is monotonically increasing for $x\geq n^2$, and has slant asymptote $$h_n(x) = x + 2n^2.$$ The distance $g_n(x)-h_n(x)=\frac{n^4}x$ is **positive and monotonically decreasing**.
3. Iterating on $n$ the inequality $$b_{n+1}\geq b_n + 2n^2,$$ valid, by \eqref{1}, for $n\geq 2$ we obtain that
   $$b_{n+1} \geq b_2 -2 + 2\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6\geq \frac{2n^3}3$$
4. Using 2. we have, for large enough $n$, \begin{eqnarray}0\leq b_{n+1}-b_n-2n^2&=&g_n(b_{n})-h_n(b_n)\leq g_n\left(\frac{2(n-1)^3}3\right)-h_n\left(\frac{2(n-1)^3}3\right)\leq \\
   &\leq&\frac{3n^4}{2(n-1)^3}\leq 3n.\end{eqnarray}
5. From 4., thus, we get $$b_n + 2n^2 \leq b_{n+1}\leq b_n + 2n^2 + 3n.$$ Iterating on $n$ yields $$b_2 -5 + \frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}3 \leq b_n \leq b_2 -5 + \frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}3 + \frac{3n(n-1)}2,$$
   and by the Squeeze Theorem $$b_n \sim \frac23 n^3.$$
   Hence $$a_n \sim \sqrt{\frac23} n^{3/2}.$$

Comment: It should be possible to prove that $a_n  \sim \sqrt {\frac{2}{3}} n^{3/2}$ mimicking the argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2679237).

Comment: @Gary, right. I'll add details as soon as I can. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: How do you know that the limit exists? You would need to show for instance that $a_n/n^{3/2}$ is monotonic.

Comment: @Gary I erroneously assumed monotonicity of $a_n$ plus the bound above were sufficient. I have to think about that. Thanks, I will leave the answer here for the moment.

Comment: Why is $n^3-2b_n$ positive? $n^3-2b_n=n^3-2a_n^2 \sim n^3 -(4/3)n^3 =-n^3/3<0$.

Comment: But it can't be because if we establish $a_n\sim \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}n^{3/2}$ then $b_n \sim (2/3)n^3 >n^3/2$.

Comment: Right I'll delete that and double check it! Found the error :)

Comment: @Gary I reviewed the answer completely; have a look, if you please, and let me know if you think now it is correct.